# Generate Excel with merged header using NPOI?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I tried to export excel sheet using NPOI like bellow but  I am unable to change the background color and set second cell value. Bellow are my code.

```
var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Commission");
var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);

var bStylehead = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
bStylehead.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Thin;
bStylehead.BorderLeft = BorderStyle.Thin;
bStylehead.BorderRight = BorderStyle.Thin;
bStylehead.BorderTop = BorderStyle.Thin;
bStylehead.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
bStylehead.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;         
bStylehead.FillBackgroundColor = HSSFColor.Green.Index;

row.CreateCell(0);
row.CreateCell(1);

var r2 = sheet.CreateRow(1);
r2.CreateCell(0, CellType.String).SetCellValue("Name");
r2.CreateCell(1, CellType.String).SetCellValue("Address");
r2.CreateCell(2, CellType.String).SetCellValue("city");
r2.CreateCell(3, CellType.String).SetCellValue("state");

var cra = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 1);  
var cra1 = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 2, 3);               
sheet.AddMergedRegion(cra);                         
sheet.AddMergedRegion(cra1);         

ICell cell = sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(0);
cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
cell.SetCellValue("Supplier Provided Data");
cell.CellStyle = bStylehead;

ICell cell1  = sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(1);
cell1.SetCellType(CellType.String);
cell1.SetCellValue("Deal Provided Data");
cell1.CellStyle = bStylehead;
```

Desired Format:

[image: Desired Format]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create two more cells because you have 2x2 merged cells for your headers:

> Supplier Provided Data
>   Deal Provided Data

Then, you'll be able to access your second header cell:

```
ICell cell1 = sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(2);
```

To set the background color, you need to use the `FillForegroundColor` property:

```
cellStyleColorGreen.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
cellStyleColorGreen.FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.Green.Index;
```

Or to make a custom color:

```
cellStyleColorCustom.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyleColorCustom).SetFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new byte[] { 198, 239, 206 }));
```

To clone a style, for example, to use the cell style for the border and add a background color, you can use:

```
cellStyleColorAndBorder.CloneStyleFrom(cellStyleBorder);
```

Full code:

```
var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Commission");
var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);

var cellStyleBorder = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyleBorder.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Thin;
cellStyleBorder.BorderLeft = BorderStyle.Thin;
cellStyleBorder.BorderRight = BorderStyle.Thin;
cellStyleBorder.BorderTop = BorderStyle.Thin;
cellStyleBorder.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
cellStyleBorder.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

var cellStyleBorderAndColorGreen = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyleBorderAndColorGreen.CloneStyleFrom(cellStyleBorder);
cellStyleBorderAndColorGreen.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyleBorderAndColorGreen).SetFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new byte[] { 198, 239, 206 }));

var cellStyleBorderAndColorYellow = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyleBorderAndColorYellow.CloneStyleFrom(cellStyleBorder);
cellStyleBorderAndColorYellow.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyleBorderAndColorYellow).SetFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new byte[] { 255, 235, 156 }));

row.CreateCell(0);
row.CreateCell(1);
row.CreateCell(2);
row.CreateCell(3);

var r2 = sheet.CreateRow(1);
r2.CreateCell(0, CellType.String).SetCellValue("Name");
r2.Cells[0].CellStyle = cellStyleBorderAndColorGreen;
r2.CreateCell(1, CellType.String).SetCellValue("Address");
r2.Cells[1].CellStyle = cellStyleBorderAndColorGreen;
r2.CreateCell(2, CellType.String).SetCellValue("city");
r2.Cells[2].CellStyle = cellStyleBorderAndColorYellow;
r2.CreateCell(3, CellType.String).SetCellValue("state");
r2.Cells[3].CellStyle = cellStyleBorderAndColorYellow;
var cra = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 1);
var cra1 = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 2, 3);
sheet.AddMergedRegion(cra);
sheet.AddMergedRegion(cra1);

ICell cell = sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(0);
cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
cell.SetCellValue("Supplier Provided Data");
cell.CellStyle = cellStyleBorderAndColorGreen;
sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(1).CellStyle = cellStyleBorderAndColorGreen;

ICell cell1 = sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(2);
cell1.SetCellType(CellType.String);
cell1.SetCellValue("Deal Provided Data");
cell1.CellStyle = cellStyleBorderAndColorYellow;
sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(3).CellStyle = cellStyleBorderAndColorYellow;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\excel\test.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    workbook.Write(fs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Arrow is on target.

Answer (score 9):

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = wb.CreateSheet("FileName");
var cra = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(firstRow, lastRow, firstCol, lastCol);
sheet.AddMergedRegion(cra);
```

Hope help you! (Use lib NPOI)